# New to ASP.NET and i have no idea why this @RenderPage isn't working

Tags: asp.net, razor

I've been tasked with updating my company's website and one of the first things I've noticed that they have they drop down menu coded on each page (roughly 60) So the first thing I would like to do is create the menu once, and call it from each page, so that I don't need to create the same menu 60 times. I know in php I could just throw in an #include and everything would be fine, but the company has forbidden me from using php and I have to work with their aspx. After doing a little research I found that asp.net has the `@RenderPage` statement which looked like it would work, I tried it out in Visual Studio Express on a simple test.vbhtml program and everything worked fine. I then went to the company's Default.aspx page and tried it and instead of rendering my menu it just displayed the `@RenderPage("_Menu.vbhtml")` line and not the menu file. Thinking I messed something up, I commented out the entire page and left a simple program at the bottom

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Main Page</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  @RenderPage("_test.vbhtml")
  <h1>Index Page Content</h1>
  <p>This is the content of the main page.</p>
 </body>
</html>
```

and I still get the same results, It doesn't Render the page and just displays my command as if I had wrapped it in a p tag. What am I doing wrong? Is .aspx incompatible with `@RenderPage`? If so how would you recommend I go about bringing in a menu from an outside file

Comment: are you trying to render a partial view inside a view? If so you would want @Html.Partial("~/Views/test.vbhtml") but it would need to be within a Razor view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Views > Shared and see if there is an `_Layout.vbhtml`, that is kind of your master page, if the menu is located in that then every page which uses the layout should display the menu.

Many MVC apps use the bootstrap theme out of the box, and the `_Layout.vbhtml` contains:

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Exceptions", "Index", "Exceptions")</li>       
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Output File","Index", "MasterFile")</li>                            
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Reports","Index","Reports")</li>      
                </ul>
                <p class="nav navbar-text navbar-right">Hello, @User.Identity.Name!</p>
            </div>
```

That sort of thing to render the menu across every page which uses the layout.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are making a big confusion between `ASP`, `ASP.NET MVC` and `Razor` view engine.

Simply put: `@RenderPage` won't work in `.aspx`. The page itself has to be a `vbhtml` file as a Razor view.

**Or** you may use `<% RenderPage(...) %>` with correct tagging.

Comment: Sadly that didn't work either. Would using a Master Page accomplish what i need to do?

Comment: Layout page, as described in the accepted answer. acts as Master Page. I really think you need some training before getting your hands dirty in the code :-) and there are plenties of tutorials to follow

Comment: I agree, this is a good one: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started